# Getting No Response When Using GetEndPoint Method and Getting An 405 Error when not using GetEndPoint Method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

Code 1:

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

```
var endPoint = context.GetEndpoint();

if (endPoint != null)
{

    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"EndPoint: {endPoint}\n");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Display Name: {endPoint.DisplayName}\n");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Request Delegate: {endPoint.RequestDelegate}\n");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Meta Data: {endPoint.Metadata}\n");
}



await next(context);
```

});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => {
endpoint.MapGet("map1", async (context) => {

```
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("In Map 1");
});

endpoint.MapPost("map2", async (context) => {

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("In Map 2");
});
```

});

app.Run(async (context) => {

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Neither in Map 1 nor in Map 2");
```

});

app.Run();

When I Run a request with a method : GET and url : /map2, window display in the browswe stuck and postman also gives an error.

Code 2:

using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();

//app.Use(async (context, next) =>
//{

//    var endPoint = context.GetEndpoint();

//    if (endPoint != null)
//    {

//        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"EndPoint: {endPoint}\n");
//        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Display Name: {endPoint.DisplayName}\n");
//        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Request Delegate: {endPoint.RequestDelegate}\n");
//        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Meta Data: {endPoint.Metadata}\n");
//    }

//    await next(context);
//});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => {
endpoint.MapGet("map1", async (context) => {

```
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("In Map 1");
});

endpoint.MapPost("map2", async (context) => {

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("In Map 2");
});
```

});

app.Run(async (context) => {

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Neither in Map 1 nor in Map 2");
```

});

app.Run();

Now when I comment out the GetEndPointMethod and run a request with method : GET and url :/map2, the browser and postman gives me a 405 Error method.

Now I understand why the second code is giving me 405 error method. What I dont understand is why the first code is not giving the same error?

I tried multiple websites but this problem is specific to me i think so please help me.

Comment: You have more than one Route.  The routes on the server probably have different authentication.  One route may allow any user while second route may only allow authenticated users.

Comment: If you send a get request to the HttpPost endpoint,  context.GetEndpoint(); will get the error, endPoint will not be null, You can change your code to `if (endPoint != null && endPoint.Metadata.Count !=0)`